# Dragon Ball Z fan fiction where Vegeta is transported to an alternate universe and into the body of a Neko slave girl

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, dragon-ball-z

I am looking for this one *Dragon Ball Z* fan fiction where Vegeta ends up being transported to an alternate universe and into the body of a Neko slave girl who committed suicide. Then Vegeta ends up on the run from Goku who became the ruler of Freiza's previous empire. At some point, Goku and Neko-Vegeta had to work together to stop this Tuffle that was attempting to kill everyone in Goku's empire using some machine that spewed out poisonous gas.

Comment: This is exactly the right place to ask after this.